# how to run sparql query against local rdf file in php

Tags: php, rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I have wrote some SPARQL queries against [DBPedia's SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/Sparql), because sometimes this endpoint is not available. I have downloaded some RDF files (e.g. **counties.rdf**).

How can I run my queries against the RDF file? I tried replacing the address of the endpoint with my local path but it does not work.

Example:

```
 var url = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";   == http://localhost/myfile/india.rdf
 var query = "
     PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
     PREFIX ABs: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
     SELECT ?capital
     WHERE {
         ?s dbpedia2:India\"@en;\ abs:capital ?capital\ 
     }";
```

Comment: Define "does not work", do you get an error (if so show it), do you get no results at all, something else entirely?  In general your question lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem, please provide a minimal complete example that demonstrates the error

Comment: My question is that I want to know how to query rdf file on my local computer. the above queries is fine via  "http://dbpedia.org/sparql".

Comment: Unless you're running a webserver locally, a URL like `http://localhost/myfile/india.rdf` won't work.  Are you sure that you don't mean something like `file://.../india.rdf` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not really used PHP and RDF **together**. Instead, I did it using Python. There we had a library called "[rdflib](https://rdflib.dev/)" which can be used to load an RDF in an object, and then execute SPARQL queries on it.

I think there is something like this in PHP. After some "googling", I came by [easyrdf](http://www.easyrdf.org) which seems to be quite similar. Their documentation provides a bunch of [examples](http://www.easyrdf.org/examples) in which I see something like "Making a SPARQL SELECT query". Hope it helps

Edit note: This example does not work for a local file. EasyRDF requires an http / https endpoint.